# pandas change attribute values to row values of object

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multiple-columns, rows

data aggregation parsed from file at the moment:

```
obj    price1*red    price1*blue    price2*red    price2*blue
a      5             7              10            12
b      15            17             20            22
```

desired outcome:

```
obj    color    price1    price2
a      red      5         7
a      blue     10        12
b      red      15        17
b      blue     20        22
```

this example is simplified. the data of the real usecase persists out of 404 columns and 10'000 of rows. The data mostly has arround 99 positions of colors and 4 different kind of pricelists (pricelists are always 4 kinds of).

I already tried a different approach from another part i programmed before in python

```
df_pricelist = pd.melt(df_pricelist, id_vars=["object_nr"], var_name='color', value_name='prices')
```

but this approach was initially used to pivot data from a single attribute to multiple lines. Or in other words only 1 cell for the different pricelists instead of multiple cells.

Where i also used assign to add the different blocks of the string to dofferent column cells.

To get all the different columns into the dataframe i use str.startswith. This way i don't have to know all the different colors there could be.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that makes use of a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#) as an intermediate step:

```
import pandas as pd

# Construct example dataframe
col_names = ["obj", "price1*red", "price1*blue", "price2*red", "price2*blue"]
data = [
    ["a", 5, 7, 10, 12],
    ["b", 15, 17, 20, 22],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)

# Convert objects column into rows index
df2 = df.set_index("obj")

# Convert columns index into two-level multi-index by splitting name strings
color_price_pairs = [tuple(col_name.split("*")) for col_name in df2.columns]
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(color_price_pairs, names=("price", "color"))

# Stack colors-level of the columns index into a rows index level
df2 = df2.stack()
df2.columns.name = ""

# Optional: convert rows index (containing objects and colors) into columns
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

This is a print-out that shows both the original dataframe `df` and the result dataframe `df2`:

```
In [1] df
Out[1]: 
  obj  price1*red  price1*blue  price2*red  price2*blue
0   a           5            7          10           12
1   b          15           17          20           22

In [2]: df2
Out[2]: 
  obj color  price1  price2
0   a  blue       7      12
1   a   red       5      10
2   b  blue      17      22
3   b   red      15      20
```